# How do I access an object outside of a subroutine?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am taking IT at school and we have to build a basic program that compares 2 characters and tells the user which one is better.

I am using a basic GUI in a winform that uses a listbox to select the character you want to compare.

However, I need to call the `selectedCharacter` object in my if statement, in order to compare the totals.

```
public void lstbxCharacter1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Character selectedCharacter = characters.ElementAt(lstbxCharacter1.SelectedIndex);

        lblName1.Text = "Name: " + selectedCharacter.getName();
        lblNinjutsu1.Text = "Ninjutsu: " + selectedCharacter.getNinjutsu();
        lblGenjutsu1.Text = "Genjutsu: " + selectedCharacter.getGenjutsu();
        lblTaijutsu1.Text = "Taijutsu: " + selectedCharacter.getTaijutsu();
        lblIntellegence1.Text = "Intellegence: " + selectedCharacter.getIntellegence();
        lblStrength1.Text = "Strength: " + selectedCharacter.getStrength();
        lblSpeed1.Text = "Speed: " + selectedCharacter.getSpeed();
        lblStamina1.Text = "Stamina: " + selectedCharacter.getStamina();
        lblHandSigns1.Text = "Hand Signs:" + selectedCharacter.getHandSigns();
        lblTotalValue1.Text = selectedCharacter.getTotal().ToString();
        pb1.Image = Image.FromFile(selectedCharacter.getImage());


    }
```

^Here is my subroutine to change characters by selecting the name from the listbox (Just ignore all the "get" methods)

```
public void displayWinner()
    {
        if ()
        {
            lblWinner.Text = "Character 1 is better";
        }
        else if ()
        {
            lblWinner.Text = "Character 2 is better";
        }
        else
        {
            lblWinner.Text = "These characters are equal";
        }

    }
```

^Here is my if statement. I am trying to make the condition something like `(selectedCharacter.getTotal() > selectedCharacter2.getTotal())` but cannot access the `selectedCharacter`.

So my question is, is there a way to access the `selectedCharacter` within the subroutine, or should I do this another way?

Thank you for your help,
:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable (such as `selectedCharacter`) cannot be used unless it is in *scope* for the code trying to access it. In C#, a set of `{}` creates a new scope. Code can access its own scope and any scope it is nested in.

Because the `selectedCharacter` variable is local to the IndexChanged method, it is not in scope for `displayWinner`. To fix it, move that variable into the **class** scope. Now both methods can access it:

```
Character selectedCharacter;
Character otherSelectedCharacter;

public void lstbxCharacter1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedCharacter = characters.ElementAt(lstbxCharacter1.SelectedIndex);
     ....
}

public void DisplayWinner()
{
   if (selectedCharacter.IsBetterThan(otherSelectedCharacter))
    ...
}
```

To avoid the case where `DisplayWinner` is called with no selection (and thus `selectedCharacter.<anything>` would throw a `NullReferenceException`), you can use a null conditional operator and null coalescing to automatically fail your check (among other ways, but this one is short and to the point).

```
if (selectedCharacter?.IsBetterThan(otherSelectedCharacter) ?? false)
```

Comment: Ok sorry to be a beta but what should the `IsBetterThan` method look like? (We literally started learning c# like 2 days ago so yeah i have no idea what i'm doing)

Comment: @BrianHudson Its just a method I defined that is a placeholder for however you are comparing characters so I didn't have to write `if()`. It could be another method in the Form also (though I would argue characters know how to compare each other).

Answer (score 1):

you need to make selectedCharacter a member variable of the form that hosts the control.

put `Character m_selectedCharacter` in the code outside the methods. (Normal to use a naming standard for member variables hence the m_ prefix)

Comment: Ok thank you. However I cannot set this to be equal to `characters.ElementAt(lstbxCharacter1.SelectedIndex)`

Comment: @BrianHudson You actually can (and the whole m_ thing is not really a standard naming convention for C#, though it is *common*)

Comment: yes - you dont have to do a naming thing, but ideally you should have someting

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I can't do `Character m_selectedCharacter = Characters.ElementAt(lstboxCharacter1.SelectedIndex);` outside the method as i am getting a **a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.characters'**

Comment: @BrianHudson Right... you still have to assign it in the method. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the access to `selectedCharacter` from another method because the variable's life cycle end after the method is executed.
If you want use selectedCharacter also outside the event `SelectedIndexChanged` you need to declare your variable in the Container that host your control. By doing this your variable will be visible to all method and property inside in the container* (also outside, it depends on [accessibility level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)). A suggestion: before use the property control that is not null, otherwise you will get a `NullPointer Exception`.
*All methods and properties except for `static` stuff

Comment: Ok thank you. How do I declare a global `selectedCharacter` variable with it still being equal to `characters.ElementAt(lstbxCharacter1.SelectedIndex)` outside of the `public void lstbxCharacter1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

Comment: Not sure class scope counts as "global". The only real members of the global scope I can think of are `static` classes. Even those reside in namespaces.

Comment: You are right @BradleyDotNET. I'm gonna specify the answer

Comment: @Tinwor I meant putting a variable at the class level is not "global scope" (at least in the way that term is used in a language like C++ where global scope is an actual thing). You do have a good point about `static` members not having access to instance members though.